# applicationWillEnterForeground vs. applicationDidBecomeActive, applicationWillResignActive vs. applicationDidEnterBackground

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiapplicationdelegate

Which is the proper delegate to implement when an application is waking up from being in the background and you want it to prep it to be active?

applicationWillEnterForeground vs applicationDidBecomeActive -- What's the difference?

Which is the proper delegate to implement for when an application is going to sleep and you want to prep it to cleanup and save data?

applicationWillResignActive vs. applicationDidEnterBackground -- What's the difference?

Also, I've noticed that applicationWillResignActive gets called when an incoming SMS or call comes in but the user chooses to click Ok and continue.  I don't want my app to take any action in these cases.  I just want it to keep running without any intermediate cleanup since the user didn't exit the app.  So, I would think it makes more sense to do cleanup work just in applicationDidEnterBackground.

I would appreciate your input on best practices to follow on choosing which delegates to implement for waking up and going to sleep as well as considering events like being interrupted by SMS/calls.

Thanks

Answer (score 490):

When waking up i.e. relaunching an app (either through springboard, app switching or URL) **`applicationWillEnterForeground:`** is called. It is only executed once when the app becomes ready for use, after being put into the background, while **`applicationDidBecomeActive:`** may be called multiple times after launch. This makes **`applicationWillEnterForeground:`** ideal for setup that needs to occur just once after relaunch.

**`applicationWillEnterForeground:` is called:**

- when app is relaunched
- before **`applicationDidBecomeActive:`**

**`applicationDidBecomeActive:` is called:**

- when app is first launched after `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`
- after **`applicationWillEnterForeground:`** if there's no URL to handle.
- after `application:handleOpenURL:` is called.
- after **`applicationWillResignActive:`** if user ignores interruption like a phone call or SMS.

**`applicationWillResignActive:` is called:**

- when there is an interruption like a phone call.

  - if user takes call **`applicationDidEnterBackground:`** is called.
  - if user ignores call **`applicationDidBecomeActive:`** is called.
- when the home button is pressed or user switches apps.
- docs say you should

  - pause ongoing tasks
  - disable timers
  - pause a game
  - reduce OpenGL frame rates

**`applicationDidEnterBackground:` is called:**

- after **`applicationWillResignActive:`**
- docs say you should:

  - release shared resources
  - save user data
  - invalidate timers
  - save app state so you can restore it if app is terminated.
  - disable UI updates
- you have 5 seconds to do what you need to and return the method

  - if you don't return within ~5 seconds the app is terminated.
  - you can ask for more time with `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:`

[The official documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate?language=objc)

Comment: One more thing to add. If you open background apps list from your app (double-click home button) and then return back to it (choose your app's preview) - `-applicationWillEnterForeground:` won't be called, only `-applicationDidEnterBackground:` (suppose, iOS don't think that it's a relaunch).

Comment: @kpower yes, that just broke my neck ... never would have thought that willEnterForeground will not be called in that case ...

Comment: Isn't it that `applicationWillEnterForeground:` will be called every time from background to foreground?! I cannot find a case that it is NOT called WITHOUT `applicationDidBecomeActive` afterwards.

Comment: This isn't accurate. applicationWillResignActive can be called without applicationDidEnterBackground

Answer (score 30):

[Managing Your App's Life Cycle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/managing_your_app_s_life_cycle) is helpful to your questions. For quick concept, you can see Figures in that document.
You can also read the comment from the code generated by the XCode Wizard. Listed as follows:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    /*
     Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. 
     This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an 
     incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application 
     and it begins the transition to the background state.
     Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down 
     OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
     */
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    /*
     Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate 
     timers, and store enough application state information to restore your 
     application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
     If your application supports background execution, this method is called 
     instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
     */
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    /*
     Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; 
     here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
     */
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    /*
     Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the 
     application was inactive. If the application was previously in the 
     background, optionally refresh the user interface.
     */
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    /*
     Called when the application is about to terminate.
     Save data if appropriate.
     See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
     */
}
```

For more detailed explanations, please refer to official document for [UIApplicationDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate)

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: Revise some descriptions and links, 2019 for now.

Answer (score 14):

I was still a bit confused with Dano's answer so I did a little test to get the flow of events in certain scenarios for my reference, but it might be useful to you too.  This is for apps that DO NOT use `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` in their info.plist.  This was conducted on an iOS 8 simulator + confirmed with iOS 7 device.  Please excuse Xamarin's event handler names.  They are very similar.

- Initial and all subsequent launches from a not-running state:

> FinishedLaunching
>
> OnActivated

- Interruption (phone call, top slide-down, bottom slide-up):
- Home button double-press listing inactive apps, then reselecting our app:

> OnResignActivation
>
> ---
>
> OnActivated

- Home button double-press listing inactive apps, selecting another app, then relaunching our app:
- Home button single press, then relaunch:
- Lock (on/off button), then unlock:

> OnResignActivation
>
> DidEnterBackground
>
> ---
>
> WillEnterForeground
>
> OnActivated

- Home button double-press, and terminate our app: (subsequent relaunch is first case)

> OnResignActivation
>
> DidEnterBackground
>
> DidEnterBackground (iOS 7 only?)

Yes, `DidEnterBackground` is called twice on iOS7 device.  Both times UIApplication state is Background. However, iOS 8 simulator does not.  This needs testing on iOS 8 device.  I will update my answer when I get my hand on it, or someone else could confirm.

Answer (score 10):

`applicationWillEnterForeground` is called:

when app is relaunched(comes from background to foreground)
This method is not invoked when app starts for the first time i.e when `applicationDidFinishLaunch` is called but only when comes from background
`applicationDidBecomeActive`

`applicationDidBecomeActive` is called

when app is first launched after `didFinishLaunching`
after `applicationWillEnterForeground` if there’s no URL to handle.
after `application:handleOpenURL:` is called.
after `applicationWillResignActive` if user ignores interruption like a phone call or SMS.
after disappearing of alertView anywhere from the application

Comment: Do you by any chance know if this was changed as of iOS 7? I remember (I could be mistaken) doing stuff (iOS 5/6) in applicationWillEnterForeground and having that run when the app first launched. As of now, in 7.1/8, you're right applicationWillEnterForeground doesn't get called on launch.

Answer (score 8):

applicationWillResignActive is called when system is asking for permissions. (in iOS 10). Just in case someone hit into the same trouble as me...

Comment: any idea what method get called after permission pop dismiss? I have this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26059927/applicationdidbecomeactive-not-called-when-launching-app-from-banner-custom-acti

Answer (score 5):

In iOS 8+ there is a subtle but important difference for taking phone call.

In iOS 7 if user takes phone call both applicationWillResignActive: and applicationDidEnterBackground: are called. But in iOS 8+ only applicationWillResignActive: is called.

Answer (score 4):

For iOS 13+ the following methods will be executed:

```
- (void)sceneWillEnterForeground:(UIScene *)scene
- (void)sceneDidBecomeActive:(UIScene *)scene
```