# Problem with background playing

Tags: iphone, background

I have a problem in understanding the following methods...I have two works to  done. 
identify when user play home button and second is to identify when application was interrupted  by phone call.

```
 - (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application ;
 - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application;
```

Comment: are you required to get to know if your audio application interrupted by phone call?

Comment: @Waqas Raja- Yes i want exactly what you write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement [AVAudioSessionDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSessionDelegate_ProtocolReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/AVAudioSessionDelegate/endInterruptionWithFlags%3a)

There are methods for `beginInterruption` and `endInterruption`

By the time the `beginInterruption` arrives, your audio has already stopped. Your application may be suspended or terminated following an interruption—for example, if a user chooses to take an incoming phone call

Comment: +1 thank you for the answer not  exactly but it really helped me to go to near to my answer....because my app access data from website and without coming back to foreground it is not possible to start buffering again

Answer (score 1):

See this handy webpage and the flowcharts there:

http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/07/understanding-ios-4-backgrounding-and-delegate-messaging/

Basically, you don't get told the reason for being backgrounded (phone call versus home button), but in some circumstances you might be able to glean what happened (e.g. appWillResignActive followed by appDidBecomeActive happens when a phone call was refused) -- however I'd be very wary about attaching interpretations to such things.

Answer (score 1):

Check this

[applicationWillEnterForeground vs. applicationDidBecomeActive, applicationWillResignActive vs. applicationDidEnterBackground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712979/applicationwillenterforeground-vs-applicationdidbecomeactive-applicationwillres)