# IOS: save an uimage when I press home button

Tags: ios, uiimage, home-directory

In my app I should color some images but I have a problem

I have three viewcontroller, and I save my image in NShomedirectory/documents

When I color I'm in thirdViewController, when I change image with an IBAction I save it in NSHomedirectory, but if I'm coloring an image and I press home button , my image is not saved when I open a second time my app;
(my app is not multitasking for some reason)
is there a way to intercep home button press?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following method is called when your app goes to background.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

you can have image saving code in this method.

Check this link for more details - [UIApplicationDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: What's the real difference with applicationWillResignActive ? cause in the link they said that it's also when the application become inactive :/

Comment: @JohnSmith - you can check this link for details - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712979/applicationwillenterforeground-vs-applicationdidbecomeactive-applicationwillre

Comment: Okay thanks, then it's better for him to use applicationDidEnterBackground cause he wants do data saving

Answer (score 0):

yes

In your AppDelegate you can overload this:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application;
```

your application enter in this function each time you click on the home button