# Reload contents at startup

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I've been banging my head against the wall for several days trying to understand how to perform an action as soon as the application starts.

Basically I want to download a plist from my website if the user turns on a switch that determines if he wants to download new contents at startup.

Point is that:

- "A" class has the method to reload the contents;
- "B" class has the switch that, if turned on, tells the delegate to perform the reload contents method as soon as the application starts

Now, I don't know how to tell the AppDelegate to run the method of class "A" if the switch of class "B" is turned on. Obviously I need to use `NSUserDefaults`, but i'm pretty lost after that.

Can anyone make things clearer? Or, is there a more comfortable workaround to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can do this using NSUserDefaults

in your class b.

```
-(void)swithChanged
 {
   NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    //check if !null
   if(![[defaults objectForKey:@"shouldDownload"]isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]){
         if([(NSNumber*)[defaults objectForKey:@"shouldDownload"]boolValue])
          {
             [defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] forKey:@"shouldDownload"];
             [defaults synchronize];
          }else{
             [defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:@"shouldDownload"];
             [defaults synchronize];

         }
     }else{
       //set your NSUserDefault here for the first time
    }

}
```

in your AppDelegate

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application{
   NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    //check if !null
   if(![[defaults objectForKey:@"shouldDownload"]isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]){
         if([(NSNumber*)[defaults objectForKey:@"shouldDownload"]boolValue])
          { 
              //you can write the downloadData method in this appDelegate,
             //[self downloadData]

             //OR
             AClass *aClass = [AClass alloc]init];
             [aClass downloadData];
          }else{
            //do not download
         }
     }else{
       //the default behaviour of app, download or not?
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! Just a question: in AppDelegate, when you've wrote [self downloadData], i should initialize my "A" class then perform the method, right!?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a post that could help you understand the flows during application start-up:
http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/07/understanding-ios-4-backgrounding-and-delegate-messaging

Also, check this post:
[applicationWillEnterForeground vs. applicationDidBecomeActive, applicationWillResignActive vs. applicationDidEnterBackground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712979/applicationwillenterforeground-vs-applicationdidbecomeactive-applicationwillre)