# Ios - Detect device orientation in background mode

Tags: ios, background, notifications, device-orientation

My app is running in background mode because I'm playing and recording audio. I wish to find the device orientation while I'm recording. I set up notification that tells me when the orientation changes and it works fine while the app is active on screen.
My problem is that when I'm moving to background mode the notifications stop coming.
Is there a way to keep getting these notifications while my app is in background mode?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can check device orientation when your app resumes from background. `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol has several methods for handling app's transition from background to foreground; check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9860393/988769) for nice writeup.

Comment: Thank you, but i want to keep getting the notifications while my app is in background. I know i can check the orientation when my app resumes.