# applicationDidBecomeActive not called when launching app from Banner/custom action

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ios8

I'm facing this weird problem while trying to implement iOS-8's new Interactive Notifications. When dealing with Local Notifications everything works as expected, but when it comes to APNS - things do not work well.

In details: I get the custom push as it should through the banner (I register only to the minimal context), but when the user taps the button that represents the custom action, my application's delegate`applicationDidBecomeActive:` is not called; In fact - the app gets stuck on an inactive mode.

The weird thing is that the app does go to active mode when launched from the Notifications screen (The one to right of the Today).
Beside that, on both cases, my delegate:

```
handleActionWithIdentifier:forRemoteNotification:completionHandler:
```

does get called with the right Identifier.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Ofer, is your action performed in the background, or does it open the application in foreground?

Comment: It defined to open the application in the foreground, and in fact it does it. Only that, as mentioned, the applicationState remains in an inactive mode.

Comment: I see. Looks like a framework bug. Have you tried reproducing the problem on iOS8.1 beta 1 (not 8.0.1!)?

Comment: Not yet, but I do plan to do it this Sunday. I'll post the result. Thanks!

Comment: Does the notification post? 
`UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification`

Comment: No, it also does not post the notification.

Comment: iOS 8.1 - bug still exists.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: No, I haven't... Are you experiencing the same issue?

Comment: Yes, I am. What a horrible bug. Please update if you have any progress. I'll do the same.

Comment: Indeed horrible, I will do so. It's good to know that I'm not the only one facing this issue.

Comment: It's interesting that you're seeing local notifications work correctly.  What we're seeing is that if you kill the app, receive an actionable foreground notification and engage the action then the app foregrounds, but didBecomeActive never gets called and the didBecomeActive notification isn't posted.  We see similar behavior if we kill the app, post a local notification from an apple watch extension and enter the app from the notification via notification center - note, this one doesn't have to be an actionable notification.

Comment: @All, facing the same issue in iOS 11 as well, applicationDidBecomeActive not called after permission alert dismiss. Pls let me know a workaround if any.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like this is an iOS 8 Bug. Found the following on Urban Airship's iOS change log document:

> iOS 8 Notes (Updated September 25, 2014)
>
> Known issues with iOS 8.0.0 that may impact your application:
>   - Applications do not enter the 'active' state when started from an interactive notification   and subsequent app sessions do not receive
>   the application:didBecomeActive delegate call or
>   UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification notification. The application
>   state never   transitions out of 'inactive' (Radar #18179525). This
>   will impact the accuracy of   reporting for applications using
>   interactive notifications.
>
> http://docs.urbanairship.com/reference/libraries/ios/latest/ios_changelog.txt

I Did not find any indication that this had been fixed in the latest iOS 8 versions, including 8.1 and 8.2-Beta, nor any workaround to deal with it.

Comment: Indeed, I'm having this. Receiving a phone call triggers applicationWillResignActive: but dismissing the phone call does not trigger applicationDidBecomeActive:. This is sad.