# How to detect if app transitioning to foreground is initiated by the user

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8

I am trying to accurately track sessions in our app, and I would like to understand how I can determine if an app open was initiated by a user, as opposed to the operating system.

I define 'session' as when the app has entered the foreground -- this may happen from interacting with a remote or local notification, explicitly opening the app, tapping a deep-link, etc.

Currently I consider a new session every time `applicationDidBecomeActive` gets called, but that can be initiated by the operating system periodically when it refreshes the app.

I don't want to use `willEnterForeground` because it's not called when the app is first opened.

I don't want to use `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` either because it gets called when a push notification occurs.

It looks like `applicationDidBecomeActive` is where this code should live, but how do I know when it is called by the system and not by the user action?

Comment: applicationDidBecomeActive: is called:

    when app is first launched after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
    after applicationWillEnterForeground: if there's no URL to handle.
    after application:handleOpenURL: is called.
    after applicationWillResignActive: if user ignores interruption like a phone call or SMS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [applicationWillEnterForeground vs. applicationDidBecomeActive, applicationWillResignActive vs. applicationDidEnterBackground](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712979/applicationwillenterforeground-vs-applicationdidbecomeactive-applicationwillre)