# app rendering OpenGL in the background

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I've attempted to prevent my app from doing any OpenGL in the background, but it's still getting killed occasionally out in the field, and I haven't been able to reproduce it yet.

The OpenGL use is for rendering document thumbnails.

**Definitively, where should OpenGL be started and stopped?**

Apple's docs are seemingly inconsistent. In the [OpenGL ES Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/ImplementingaMultitasking-awareOpenGLESApplication/ImplementingaMultitasking-awareOpenGLESApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH5-SW1), we have:

> In your app’s applicationWillEnterForeground: method, re-create any objects and restart your animation timer.

And in the [App Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions.html), we have:

> Apps that use OpenGL ES for drawing must not use these methods to prepare their drawing environment. Instead, defer any OpenGL ES drawing calls to the applicationDidBecomeActive: method.

[Apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712979/applicationwillenterforeground-vs-applicationdidbecomeactive-applicationwillre), `applicationWillEnterForeground` is called before `applicationDidBecomeActive`. That wold mean that starting animation in `applicationWillEnterForeground` would not defer drawing calls to `applicationDidBecomeActive`.

Currently, I'm doing the following:

- Start thumbnail rendering in `applicationDidBecomeActive` and `applicationWillEnterForeground`
- Stop thumbnail rendering in `applicationWillResignActive` per [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/ImplementingaMultitasking-awareOpenGLESApplication/ImplementingaMultitasking-awareOpenGLESApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH5-SW1).

I'm using an `OperationQueue` for thumbnail rendering and do the following to stop the queue:

```
func stopQueue() {
    // Ensure all operations are finished so we don't
    // call OpenGL while the app is backgrounded.
    workerQueue.waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished()
    workerQueue.isSuspended = true
}
```